# if my array look like this in php, how should i fetch the entity?

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array, using print_r. How should i for example get titles?

```
Array ( 

        [0] => Array ( [homework_id] => 2 [title] => english0610 [due_date] => 2012-10-09 00:00:00 [description] => english [key] => 12345 [author] => tom [attachment] => [group_id] => TJ10S1 [create_date] => 2012-10-07 00:00:00 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [homework_id] => 1 [title] => math0610 [due_date] => 2012-10-08 00:00:00 [description] => math homework for today [key] => 12345 [author] => tom [attachment] => [group_id] => TJ10S1 [create_date] => 2012-10-06 00:00:00 ) 
);
```

Comment: Tried google, the PHP manual, study some book?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
echo "<pre>"  ;
foreach($list as $value)
{
    echo $value['title']  , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but i was writing like this $list[$i]["title"] to get the title, why doesnt it work?